# awk when matching and printing two files based on one column

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files (delimiter is tab)

File1: `db.txt`

```
string1 string2 string3 001 string4
string5 string6 string7 002 string8
string9 string10 string11 003 string12
```

File2: `query.txt`

```
id1 001
id2 003
```

and I wand to match file1 and file2 and print (if there is a match) column 1 to 5 of `db.txt` and column 1 of `query.txt`

I tried using awk, here my code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}NR==FNR{a[$2]=$4;next}$4 in a{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,a[$1]}' query.txt db.txt
```

but I only get a file with matches (? I at least think so) and columns of the `db.txt` file

**EDIT:** my more complex `db2.txt`

```
string1 <TAB> string2 <TAB> 9999 abc dehi [way:pn9999] <TAB> 001 <TAB> org; string3 string4
string5 <TAB> string6 <TAB> 9999 dwd meti [way:pn8999] <TAB> 002 <TAB> org2; string7
string8 <TAB> string9 <TAB> 9999 dwd meti [way:pn7999] <TAB> 003 <TAB> org4; string10
```

Comment: Is that key always in the 4th field of the `db` file?

Comment: a different key sometimes, but yes

Comment: follow up question: I have a problem with two slightely different files. I want to match 2 files based on the first column, when there is a match it should print column 2 of file1 and file2. So that is my code: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR { a[$1] = $1; next } $1 in a { print a[$2], $2 }'`

Comment: Post it as a new question, you get more coverage for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR { a[$2] = $1; next }
$4 in a { print $0, a[$4] }' query.txt db.txt

string1 string2 string3 001 string4 id1
string9 string10 string11 003 string12 id2
```

Comment: yes that works perfectly for the example I posted, but somehow it does not work for my files; I have some spaces in the columns

Comment: Space is field separator by default. Can you post realistic example data in question so that I can understand and modify my answer.

Comment: thank you for your patience, I added a better example for by `db.txt`

Comment: ok try tab as delimiter: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} FNR == NR { a[$2] = $1; next } $4 in a { print $0, a[$4] }' query.txt db.txt`

Comment: thank you very much, that did the job! I actually tried the `FS=OFS` option before but somehow it failed

Answer (score 1):

```
AMD$ cat f1
id1 001
id2 003

AMD$ cat f2
string1 string2 string3 001 string4
string5 string6 string7 002 string8
string9 string10 string11 003 string12

AMD $ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} {for(i in a) if(index($0,i)) print a[i], $0}' f1 f2
id1 string1 string2 string3 001 string4
id2 string9 string10 string11 003 string12
```

Comment: And depending on the amount of records in `f1` vs. if there is always 5 fields to check against it might be more efficient to `for` loop the fields. We of course cannot guess the number of records.

Comment: the `db.txt` is huge compared to the `query.txt`